# How do I get mouse acceleration feeling the same as in Mac OS?

Tags: mouse, cursor, xinput, mouse-pointer, libinput

I only seem to have the option of choose between "flat" and "adaptive" mouse acceleration profiles. "Adaptive" feels too mild.

The closest I've gotten is switching to the "adaptive" profile, switching from Wayland to Xorg, using `xset m 7/2 1`, (`xset m` maxes out at an acceleration argument of 3.5) and setting my mouse to a low DPI setting and the speed to a high setting, but this arrangement feels fragile and overly hacky for what feels like should be a technically simple task, and the acceleration *still* doesn't feel quite right.

I can't see any properties configurable via xinput provided by libinput for configuring acceleration. (There is `libinput Accel Speed`, but that seems to control speed rather than acceleration)

Something like ControllerMate's (on Mac OS) capacity for setting mouse acceleration curves [see: [default](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pbxiE.png), [custom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EX1qD.png)] seems like it would be an easy way of solving this problem, but ControllerMate is Mac OS only and I don't know of a tool for Linux that offers the same functionality.

As unpopular as the opinion is, I *like* mouse acceleration, and I think the curves used by default in Mac OS feel the most comfortable. As much as I try, I can't keep the mouse acceleration in linux from feeling unnatural or stilted to me. I've tried getting used to it, but I'm reminded how off it feels when I boot into OS X and it doesn't feel off at all.